# Reference for Galois theory of local fields

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

I found that I've never seriously studied about Galois theory of local fields, so I'm trying to find a good reference with some of (good) exercises. Here's a motivation:

---

When I studied abstract algebra, I did some computations about Galois groups of certain polynomials (over $\mathbb{Q}$, obviously), for degree 3 and (some of) degree 4 and 5 polynomials. I remember that Dummit & Foote's algebra is a very good references with good exercies. In case of local fields, I know that the Galois groups are solvable since we have a filtration of ramification groups. However, I don't have any experience of computing Galois groups of a given polynomial (over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, for example). For degree $\leq 3$, I think there shouldn't be a big difference. For example, in case of degree 3, Galois group of a splitting field of a given cubic polynomial is completely determined by *squareness* of a discriminant, and for local field we can use Hansel's lemma to determine whether a given discriminant is square or not (for $\mathbb{Q}$, it is much easier, if one have a sufficiently good computational power when discriminant is huge). The biggest difference should occur in degree 5, since $A_{5}$ is the smallest non-solvable group and it can't be a Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ or other local fields. A Galois group of a splitting field of $f(x) = x^{5}+20x + 16$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $A_{5}$, and basically I want to know what is a Galois group of it over $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ (for all $p$). My guess is that computing Galois group would be much easier over local fields even for high degree polynomials, in contrast to over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: For $p=37$, I see that polynomial has a root close to $1$ in $\mathbb Q_p$, in particular is reducible ... SCNR. But seriously, the first thing to check is: How does your polynomial behave modulo $p$.

Comment: Hopefully somebody writes an answer containing the concept of Newton polygons. Also, https://www.lmfdb.org/padicField/ might be a helpful resource.

Comment: The discriminant of $f(x) := x^5 + 20x + 16$ is $2^{16}5^6$, so if $p$ is not $2$ or $5$ then $f(x) \bmod p$ is separable and thus its splitting field over $\mathbf Q_p$ is unramified and hence has a cyclic Galois group. For example, $f(x) \bmod 3$ is irreducible and $f(x) \equiv (x-4)(x-5)(x^3+2x^2+5x+5) \bmod 7$, so the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbf Q_3$ is cyclic of degree $5$ and the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbf Q_7$ is cyclic of degree $3$.  There is not a simple pattern that describes how $f(x) \bmod p$ decomposes into irreducible factors as $p$ varies.